# GLSL : Passing whole mesh to Geometry Shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, mesh, hittest

I've been searching the net for an answer without success... So i turn to you.

I'm trying to implement a shader that could give me the thickness of a mesh through a color map (or at least a two state color : over or under threshold) with GLSL.
I' would need to perform hittest from a vertex, with its reversed normal as vector. And get the distance to the closest hit point on the mesh.

I've already done the hittest function but i can't wrap my head around parsing the whole mesh in geometry shader.

Here is a simplified version of the geometry shader:

```
        in VS_GS_VERTEX
        {
            vec3 normal;
        } vertex_in[];

        out GS_FS_VERTEX
        {
            vec3 color;
        } vertex_out;


        layout (triangles) in;
        layout (line_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

        uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
        uniform mat4 viewMatrix;
        uniform mat4 modelMatrix;



    void main(void)
    {
        float negate = -1.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i += 3)
        {
            vec4 position1 = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
            vec4 position2 = gl_in[i + 1].gl_Position;
            vec4 position3 = gl_in[i + 2].gl_Position;
            vec3 target1 = vec3(position1.xyz + normalize(vertex_in[i].normal) * negate);
            vec3 target2 = vec3(position2.xyz + normalize(vertex_in[i + 1].normal) * negate);
            vec3 target3 = vec3(position3.xyz + normalize(vertex_in[i + 2].normal) * negate);
            for (int j = 0; j < gl_in.length(); j++)
            {
                vec4 positiontest = gl_in[j].gl_Position;
                if (position1 != positiontest)
                {
                    vec3 pointTouche;
                    if (hit(position1.xyz, target1, positiontest.x, positiontest.y, positiontest.z, out pointTouche))
                    {
                        float distance = length(position1 - pointTouche);
                        if (distance < 10)
                        {
                            vec3 PointerColor = vec3(1, 0, 0);
                            vertex_out.color = PointerColor;
                            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * position1;
                            EmitVertex();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            vec3 PointerColor = vec3(0, 0, 1);
                            vertex_out.color = PointerColor;
                            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * position1;
                            EmitVertex();
                        }
                    }
                }


                if (position2 != positiontest)
                {
                    vec3 pointTouche;
                    if (hit(position2.xyz, target2, positiontest.x, positiontest.y, positiontest.z, out pointTouche))
                    {
                        float distance = length(position2 - pointTouche);
                        if (distance < 10)
                        {
                            vec3 PointerColor = vec3(1, 0, 0);
                            vertex_out.color = PointerColor;
                            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * position2;
                            EmitVertex();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            vec3 PointerColor = vec3(0, 0, 1);
                            vertex_out.color = PointerColor;
                            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * position2;
                            EmitVertex();
                        }
                    }
                }


                if (position3 != positiontest)
                {
                    vec3 pointTouche;
                    if (hit(position3.xyz, target3, positiontest.x, positiontest.y, positiontest.z, out pointTouche))
                    {
                        float distance = length(position3 - pointTouche);
                        if (distance < 10)
                        {
                            vec3 PointerColor = vec3(1, 0, 0);
                            vertex_out.color = PointerColor;
                            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * position3;
                            EmitVertex();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            vec3 PointerColor = vec3(0, 0, 1);
                            vertex_out.color = PointerColor;
                            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix * position3;
                            EmitVertex();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            EndPrimitive();
        }
    }";
```

If somebody has any idea, it would be much appreciated.
Thanks all.

Comment: That sounds like a XY-problem. If you just need to calculate the thickness of a mesh, the algorithm you describe doesn't sound like a good idea. Also, there is no way to pass a whole mesh as input to the geometry shader (besides of using an SSBO).

Comment: For now, i've been doing it on CPU then passing a color Array to GLSL. 
I know that there are some shaders that compute glass like behaviours, but they need 1 (or more) ray (usually the camera lookdirection). I would like that ray to be a triangle normal as i pass through the geometry shader